# Why MVC in Durandal VS project template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, durandal

All the action is client side in a SPA app. The Visual Studio Durandal and Hot Towel project templates both serve the SPA out of an ASP.NET MVC application.

What, if anything, does the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure bring to the party? As far I can see all it does is make it hard to serve a WCF Web Service (ajax enabled) out of the project web.

Yet *both* of the project templates are set up like this. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, ASP.NET MVC in this template is not necessary. All it does is serve the initial Razor template for the SPA and provides you with the bundling and optimization support of all the client side javascript resources for the application so that when you deploy your application you don't end up with gazillions of HTTP requests from the client to fetch all the .js crap necessary for the application to work. Of course you could perfectly fine have used the bundling feature outside of ASP.NET MVC in a simple and plain ASP.NET web application.

Comment: That's what I've done and since it works very well, I thought I should pose the question.

Comment: I think you have answered my question but I hope you will expand on your comment about using bundling in a plain ASP.NET application, perhaps with a link to an msdn topic, or some search terms.

Answer (score 0):

> What, if anything, does the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure bring to the party?

See the [documentation](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/):

> Hot Towel builds on the familiar and powerful ASP.NET MVC structure.
>
> - App_Start
> - Content
> - Controllers
> - Models
> - Scripts
> - Views

---

> As far I can see all it does is make it hard to serve a WCF Web Service (ajax enabled) out of the project

You can't just right-click your project and add a new WCF Service?

Comment: I did exactly that - "just right-click and add a new WCF service." It compiled fine but I couldn't seem to invoke it from the client. The same service works fine out of an empty web project.

Comment: @Peter perhaps that's a configuration issue, you should just be able to host a WCF service from any Web Application project.

Comment: I suspect the method paths were being treated as invalid routes. It may be possible to map this correctly but I think the need to figure out how and then do so can reasonably be described as "making it hard to serve".

Comment: @PeterWone Most likely, you just need to configure your routes on the server side.  The whole point of WCF is to abstract away services in such a way that they can be called from many different types of client.